# Configure and Run Polyspace by MATLAB APIs

Tags: matlab

Configure and Run polyspace by MATLAB APIs

I want to configure and run Polypsace by means of MATLAB APIs and I used the following code for configuration:

```
ModelName = 'MyModel';
open_system(ModelName);
proj=polyspace.Project;
proj.Configuration=polyspace.Options('C');
proj.Configuration.TargetCompiler.Compiler = 'generic';
proj.Configuration.CodingRulesCodeMetrics.EnableMisraC3 = true;
proj.Configuration.CodingRulesCodeMetrics.MisraC3Subset = 'mandatory-required';
```

when I used the following command to link the configuration to the model:

```
proj.Configuration = polyspace.ModelLinkOptions(ModelName);
```

But after linking the configuration to the model, the configurations reset to the default value, and Misra gets disabled.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should launch

```
 proj.Configuration = polyspace.ModelLinkOptions(ModelName);
```

just after

```
 proj=polyspace.Project;
```

and not at the end of all your commands, because polyspace.ModelLinkOptions will load the project again, and then reset the options set previously.
Try something like:

```
ModelName = 'MyModel';
open_system(ModelName);
proj=polyspace.Project;
proj.Configuration = polyspace.ModelLinkOptions(ModelName);
proj.Configuration=polyspace.Options('C');
proj.Configuration.TargetCompiler.Compiler = 'generic';
proj.Configuration.CodingRulesCodeMetrics.EnableMisraC3 = true;
proj.Configuration.CodingRulesCodeMetrics.MisraC3Subset = 'mandatory-required';

proj.Configuration.ResultsDir = fullfile(pwd,'results');
run(proj, 'bugFinder');
```